# How to get error description once error occured during sql statement execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and writing a stored procedure which inserts and updates records in a table. This procedure will be scheduled for some time. Whenever there is a error I am logging that error in another table. But I need actual error message but unable to get the same.

I have used this:

```
SET @ErrNum = @@ERROR
SET @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
```

But my problem is I'm not getting the actual error message. I am able to get error number.

Please suggest what needs to be done for actual message to get from SQL Server prompt after execution of SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ERROR_MESSAGE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx) should do the trick.

```
  BEGIN TRY
        SELECT 1/0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is valid what you're doing. In all scripts you can see something like that

```
 DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(max)
 DECLARE @ErrorMessageOriginal nvarchar(max)
 DECLARE @Error int 
 DECLARE @ReturnCode int
 
 SET @Error = 0
 SET @ReturnCode = 0

 SET @Error = ERROR_NUMBER()
 SET @ReturnCode = @Error
 SET @ErrorMessageOriginal = ERROR_MESSAGE()
 SET @ErrorMessage = 'Msg ' + CAST(@Error AS nvarchar) + ', ' + ISNULL(@ErrorMessageOriginal,'')
 RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,16,1) WITH NOWAIT
```

But there is error that you want to handle by yourself like that from [MSDN source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx):

## Using @@ERROR to detect a specific error

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
UPDATE HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory
    SET PayFrequency = 4
    WHERE BusinessEntityID = 1;

IF @@ERROR = 547
   PRINT N'A check constraint violation occurred.';
GO
```